# Using a the class PurchJournalMatch_Invoice which requires a form as a parameter

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

Is there any way to make use of the functionality of a class which requires a form parameter, but call from a class?

For example, I am looking to automate some purchase invoice matching to purchase order receipts, and the classes which are used to handle the matching are;

```
PurchJournalMatch_Invoice
SalesPurchJournalSelect
```

To make use of the functionality in these classes I need to pass a form as a parameter, but I want to match the PO receipts to invoice lines in a class to be called periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into `\Classes\CustVendOpenTransManager`?

Here's a blog post that talks a little about a use for it:
http://daxdude.blogspot.com/2013/02/remove-marked-for-settlement-open.html

Comment: I thought this was just for marking transactions for settlement/payment rather than receipt matching